# Converting a row into column keeping one field based on flags in Access

Tags: rows, flags, transpose

I am trying to find an answer to a question that I am trying to solve in Access. I can retrieve the following data from my input spreadsheet:

Recid    Cat1     Cat2      Cat3

1          Yes        Yes        No

2              Yes        Yes        Yes

3              No        Yes        No

4              Yes        Yes        No

5              No           No         Yes

I would like to create a new table that contains only the recid and the associated categories that have "yes" as the value.

Recid   Category
1   Cat1 
1   Cat2 
2   Cat1
2   Cat2
2   Cat3
3   Cat2
4   Cat1
4   Cat2
5   Cat3

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UNION ALL` query to convert your column data into rows:

```
select recid, cat1 as Category
from yourtable
where cat1 = 'Yes'
union all
select recid, cat2 as category
from yourtable
where cat2 = 'Yes'
union all
select recid, cat3 as category
from yourtable
where cat3 = 'Yes'
```